# Need help regarding how to use cJSON library in windows

Tags: c, json, cjson

I am facing **undefined reference** issue in vs code when I run program with cJSON.h file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cJSON.h"

int main() {
    const char *json_string = "JSON STRING":
    cJSON *json = cJSON_Parse(json_string);
    
    if (json != NULL) {
        cJSON *rootObject = json; // The root object of the parsed JSON

        cJSON *currentItem = rootObject->child; // Start traversing from the first element

        while (currentItem != NULL) {
            if (currentItem->type == cJSON_Object) {
                printf("Key: %s is an object.\n", currentItem->string);
                // Perform operations specific to an object here
            }

            currentItem = currentItem->next; // Move to the next element
        }

        cJSON_Delete(json); // Clean up cJSON object
    } else {
        printf("Failed to parse JSON.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error is
[image]

I have tried with below way.
[image]

But still I am facing the issue.

This is the output
[image]

Comment: **undefined reference** it's only a small part of the complete error message. What complete errors do you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Do not post your errors as screenshots. Show the actual command you're running, and the resulting output.

Comment: Try `g++ -c example.cpp` and then `g++ -o example example.o cJSON.o` (providing cJSON.o has already been built. And then tell us what happens

Comment: @Jabberwocky It is working now. Thanks for your help. Can you please explain me where I was going wrong ?

Comment: @coder I'm not quite sure, possibly bad usage of the ar command. You should probably ask a new question specifically about the usage of ar for your use case. Or just change the title of the question and adjust the tags accordingly. And while you're at it, replace the pictures of etxt with properly formatted text.

Comment: In the pictures, the `-L` option is set to the root directory `/`. Is that where the libcjson.a file is?